# how switch in javascript works when it satisfy all cases condition

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, switch-statement

```
switch (true) {
                case (angle<20):
                    console.log("case1")
                    break;

                case (angle<70):
                    console.log("case2")
                    break;

                case (angle<110):
                    console.log("case3")
                    break;

                case (angle<160):
                    console.log("case4")
                    break;
                ... and so on until 360

}
```

the given code above is working well.
i just curious how it able to map out that angle 15 is fall on case 1. 
while 15 satisfying all case condition

unable to find any clue in google.. so im asking here
another topic been raise before. but i dont really get it still
[some clue here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42147745/how-switch-statement-works)

Comment: Because of `break`.

Comment: switch case will break after the variable encounter the first condition it satisfy, check the [documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/switch), the best way to know how it works is to read the documentation.

Comment: This has nothing to do with Java. Please remove the Java tag. Java and JavaScript are not related.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A switch statement executes the block for the first `case` that it matches (as per the order the case statements are listed top to bottom).

If that `case` contains a `break`, then no other `case` statements are matched as execution will resume after the `switch` block.

Comment: Thanks. 
this is as i expected.
however there is some doubt come in as read this jump table stuff

https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/switch-vs-else/

Answer (score 0):

Because of `break;` the switch case will *break* after the `angle` variable encounters the first case which satisfies the condition.

Answer (score 0):

switch case follow top to bottom approach.
So Try reverse condition

```
switch (true) {
   case (angle>300):
       console.log("case1")
       break;

   case (angle>250):
       console.log("case2")
       break;

   case (angle>200):
       console.log("case3")
       break;

   ... and so on
}
```

Comment: is there a specific reason why it must top to bottom?.. logically should be no diff

Answer (score -1):

The magic is on the use of the optional **break** statement, remember this:

> The optional break statement associated with each case label ensures
>   that the program breaks out of switch once the matched statement is
>   executed and continues execution at the statement following switch. If
>   break is omitted, the program continues execution at the next
>   statement in the switch statement.

What happens if you delete the break statements on each **case** clause?

I think that this quote solve your doubt.